# SilverStripe Fluent - How to prevent fallback to querystring on custom controllers?

Tags: php, silverstripe

Using the `LocalMenu` template from fluent to get a language switcher gives me "wrong" links for my custom controllers and dataobjects which I display as page.

So I have both. Controllers as pages and dataobjects on other custom controllers which are displayed as pages.

Instead of `en/sompage/foobar` I receive `somepage/foobar?l=en_US`

I think that's caused by my wrong implementation of the `Link` function on those dataobjects and controllers.

How can I do it correct? I can't find anything about that. That's my current code:

```
  public function Link($action = null) {
    $parent = MyParentPage::get()->first()->URLSegment;
    $home = RootURLController::get_default_homepage_link();

    if($parent != $home) {
      $url = $parent . '/';
    } else {
      $url = null;
    }

    return Director::baseURL() . $this->fluentUrlSegment() . $url . 'controller-segment';
  }
```

and

```
  public function fluentUrlSegment() {
    if(class_exists('Fluent')) {
      $locale = Fluent::current_locale();
      $fluentConfig = Fluent::create()->config();

      if($fluentConfig->default_locale != $locale) {
        if($fluentConfig->aliases && isset($fluentConfig->aliases[$locale])) {
          $locale = $fluentConfig->aliases[$locale];
        }

        $locale = $locale . '/';
      } else {
        $locale = '';
      }
    } else {
      $locale = '';
    }

    return $locale;
  }
```

fluent config

```
---
Name: projectfluentconfig
After: '#fluentconfig'
---
Fluent:
  disable_default_prefix: true
  detect_locale: true
  remember_locale: true
  default_locale: de_DE
  locales:
    - de_DE
    - en_US
  aliases:
    de_DE: de
    en_US: en
  field_exclude:
---
Name: projectfluentconfig
After: '#fluenti18nconfig'
---
i18n:
  default_locale: de_DE
```

## Update

Thanks to wmk's answer I could improve my link function. Unfortunately it still didn't change anything on the links in fluents locale menu.

Instead of `geschichte/..` and `en/geschichte/..` I receive `geschichte/..?l=de_DE` and `geschichte/..?l=en_US` on the german site and `en/geschichte/..?l=de_DE` and `en/geschichte/..?l=en_US` on the english one.

Could it be that fluent is ignoring those link functions completely? Did I still made a mistake or missed something? Here's my shortend code [Controller](https://www.pastiebin.com/5925300e663f3), [DataObject](https://www.pastiebin.com/59253051c3698), [Routes](https://www.pastiebin.com/592530a5af207), [Extensions](https://www.pastiebin.com/592530ce6cb2a) & [Fluent Config](https://www.pastiebin.com/592530ec0b3c3)

Any suggestions?

## Update 2

The `LocaleLink` function in the `FluentSiteTree` class seems to be the "problem"

Comment: Is english your default locale? Can you share your config? There's a setting to remove the default locale from URLs

Comment: it's german. I edited my question and added the config

Comment: do you have a custom controller for your dataobject or is it just a sublink of a page?

Comment: @wmk custom controller that extends page_controller. the link function above is from this controller

Comment: @csy_dot_io is that controller related to a page in CMS?

Comment: @wmk no it isn't

Answer (score 1):

You already grab a Page from the DB and take the URLSegment. Why not utilize that page's `Link()` method? This should already have the fluent stuff set.

Then concat the link parts with `Controller::join_links()`

```
public function Link($action = null) {
    //maybe parent::Link() also works, depending on your code structure
    $parent = MyParentPage::get()->first()->Link(); 

    return Controller::join_links($parent, 'controller-segment', $action);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that made the link creation much easier an cleaner. Unfortunately it still didn't change anything on the links in fluents locale menu. I've made an update to my question perhaps you've got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

That's not really an answer but a workaround.

I managed it to get it working by adding the `FluentExtension` also to the Controller and on that Controller I've implemented my own `LocaleLink` function.

For any one else stuck here and until there's a real solution, here's my working code [Controller](https://www.pastiebin.com/592544f87ccba), [DataObject](https://www.pastiebin.com/59253051c3698), [Routes](https://www.pastiebin.com/592530a5af207), [Extensions](https://www.pastiebin.com/5925461b77831) & [Fluent Config](https://www.pastiebin.com/592530ec0b3c3)

And if you wan't to use a translated urlsegment for the controller you could use this link function

```
  public function Link($action = null) {
    $homepage = Page::get()->find('URLSegment', RootURLController::get_homepage_link());
    $parent = $homepage->Link();

    $urlByLocale = [
      'de_DE' => 'geschichte',
      'en_US' => 'story',
    ];

    return Controller::join_links($parent, $urlByLocale[Fluent::current_locale()], $action);
  }
```

and change the routes like that

```
  'de/geschichte//$URLSegment!' => [
    'Controller' => 'Story_Controller',
    'l' => 'de_DE'
  ],
  'en/story//$URLSegment!' => [
    'Controller' => 'Story_Controller',
    'l' => 'en_US'
  ],
```

Would be great if someone will find a "nicer" way to achieve that.